# How can i debug DevOps File Transform task

Tags: bash, azure-devops

I am fairly new to DevOps.
I currently have a release pipeline where i need to set a value in various JSON files using a variable value which I'm using a file transform task to do.

The transform task reports that it has run successfully but before i add the next step into the pipeline i want to sanity check the transformation has correctly occurred otherwise it's going to screw with all the data in my database if it's wrong and i deploy all these changes.  Is there a bash command or similar that i can run so that i can see the contents of the transformed file in the release logging/debug window?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share some methods to get the file content in Release Pipeline.

**Method 1:**

You could directly use Powershell Script to get the file content:

For example:

```
Write-Host "Custom Logs:"
Get-Content $(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)\_filetransform\configfolder\web.config
```

You could get the file path in the release log.

[image]

Result:

[image]

**Method 2:**

You could try to use this extension: [File Content to Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-file-to-variable). This task could show the file content to the release log.

For example:

Task Definition:

[image]

Note: Disable the `Add New Lines Characters` option, the file content will be output in original format.

**Method 3:**

You could use [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#uploadfile-upload-a-file-that-can-be-downloaded-with-task-logs) to upload the file and download all log files.

> Write-host "##vso[task.uploadfile]"
>
> The file is then available as part of the release logs. When you
> download all the logs associated with the release, you will be able to
> retrieve this file as well.